# multi step form and model inheritance in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have seen this approach in many web applications (e.g. when you subscribe for an insurance), but I can't find a good way to implement it in django. I have several classes in my model which inherit from a base class, and so they have several fields in common. In the create-view I want to use that inheritance, so first ask for the common fields and then ask for the specific fields, depending on the choices of the user.

Naive example, suppose I want to fill a database of places

```
class Place(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Restaurant(Place):
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class SportField(Place):
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Now I would like to have a create view when there are the common fields (name and address) and then the possibility to choose the type of place (Restaurant / SportField). Once the kind of place is selected (or the user press a "Continue" button) new fields appear (I guess to make it simple the page need to reload) and the old one are still visible, already filled.

I have seen this approach many times, so I am surprised there is no standard way, or some extensions already helping with that (I have looked at Form Wizard from django-formtools, but not really linked to inheritance), also doing more complicated stuff, as having more depth in inheritance.

Comment: so you need to collect details to name, adddress, cuisine, website if it is a restaurant and name, address, sport if it is sports. This should be on a single page.Right ?

Comment: @AbhijithK, it can be on two pages, first ask for the common fields, then the specific one. Better if one the same page.

Answer (score 5):

**models.py**

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    
class Restaurant(Place):
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class SportField(Place):
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('restaurant', 'Restaurant'), ('sport', 'Sport'),)
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}))
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address'}))
    type = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onChange':'renderForm();'}))
    cuisine = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Cuisine'}))
    website = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Website'}))
    sport = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Sport'}))
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from .models import Restaurant, SportField
from .forms import CustomForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View


class CustomView(View):

    def get(self, request,):
        form = CustomForm()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'form':form})

    def post(self, request,):
        data = request.POST
        name = data['name']
        address = data['address']
        type = data['type']
        if(type == 'restaurant'):
            website = data['website']
            cuisine = data['cuisine']
            Restaurant.objects.create(
                name=name, address=address, website=website, cuisine=cuisine
            )
        else:
            sport = data['sport']
            SportField.objects.create(name=name, address=address, sport=sport)
        return HttpResponse("Success")
```

**templates/home.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function renderForm() {
            var type =
                document.getElementById("{{form.type.auto_id}}").value;
            if (type == 'restaurant') {
                document.getElementById("{{form.website.auto_id}}").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("{{form.cuisine.auto_id}}").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("{{form.sport.auto_id}}").style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById("{{form.website.auto_id}}").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("{{form.cuisine.auto_id}}").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("{{form.sport.auto_id}}").style.display = 'block';
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="renderForm()">
    <form method="post" action="/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.name}}<br>
        {{form.address}}<br>
        {{form.type}}<br>
        {{form.website}}
        {{form.cuisine}}
        {{form.sport}}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Add templates folder in settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ...
]
```

Comment: it doesn't seem very maintainable, take into account I may have a lot of subclasses. In the real case the form is going to explode, I was thinking to two forms, one generic and one specific of the type selected on the first stage. I prefer automatic form, every time I add a subclass I need to change the form... also in the view you have a hard coded switch for each subclass...

Comment: @RuggeroTurra I think in views you need to add some switching logic since you are using multiple models.

Comment: sure, but not in this explicit way by hand

Answer (score 2):

I've created a 2-page working example using modified [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/).

When the form is submitted on the first page, an object of `place_type` is created. The user is then redirected to the second page where they can update existing details and add additional information.

No separate `ModelForm`s are needed because the `CreateView` and `UpdateView` automatically generate the forms from the relevant object's model class.

A single template named `place_form.html` is required. It should render the `{{ form }}` tag.

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Place(models.Model):
    """
    Each tuple in TYPE_CHOICES contains a child class name
    as the first element.

    """
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Restaurant', 'Restaurant'),
        ('SportField', 'Sport Field'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    place_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('place_update', args=[self.pk])

# Child models go here...
```

```py
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.PlaceCreateView.as_view(), name='place_create'),
    path('<pk>/', views.PlaceUpdateView.as_view(), name='place_update'),
]
```

```py
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.forms.models import construct_instance, modelform_factory
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from . import models

class PlaceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.Place
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If a `place_type` is selected, it is used to create an 
        instance of that Model and return the url.

        """
        place_type = form.cleaned_data['place_type']
        if place_type:
            klass = getattr(models, place_type)
            instance = klass()
            obj = construct_instance(form, instance)
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.get_absolute_url())
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PlaceUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('place_create')
    template_name = 'place_form.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """
        If the place has a `place_type`, get that object instead.

        """
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
        if pk is not None:
            obj = models.Place.objects.get(pk=pk)
            if obj.place_type:
                klass = getattr(models, obj.place_type)
                obj = klass.objects.get(pk=pk)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(
                "PlaceUpdateView must be called with an object pk in the URLconf."
            )
        return obj

    def get_form_class(self):
        """
        Remove the `place_type` field.

        """
        model = self.object.__class__
        return modelform_factory(model, exclude=['place_type',])
```

Comment: not sure what is happening in `PlaceCreateView`. You are creating a subclass instance (e.g. Restaurant) but without all the needed information. Is that possibile? Doesn't it complain?

Comment: @RuggeroTurra Yes, you can create/save instances without all necessary fields. You only get stopped when validating modelforms. In this case, the `Place` modelform has all necessary information.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra Just to be thorough, the [object validation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) state "full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call your model’s save() method".

Answer (score 1):

We did something similar manually, we created the views and forms based on design and did the linkage based on if conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I think a nice solution would be to dynamically access subclasses of the main class and then do the necessary filtering/lists building.

**UPD:** I've spent some more time today on this question and made a "less raw" solution that allows to use the inheritance.

You can also check the code below deployed [here](https://voitixler.ru/playground/inheritance). It has only one level of inheritance (as in example), though, the approach is generic enough to have multiple levels

**views.py**

```
def inheritance_view(request):
    all_forms = {form.Meta.model: form for form in forms.PlaceForm.__subclasses__()}
    all_forms[models.Place] = forms.PlaceForm

    places = {cls._meta.verbose_name: cls for cls in models.Place.__subclasses__()}

    # initiate forms with the first one
    context = {
        'forms': [forms.PlaceForm(request.POST)],
    }

    # check sub-forms selected on the forms and include their sub-forms (if any)
    for f in context['forms']:
        f.sub_selected = request.POST.get('{}_sub_selected'.format(f.Meta.model._meta.model_name))
        if f.sub_selected:
            sub_form = all_forms.get(places.get(f.sub_selected))
            if sub_form not in context['forms']:
                context['forms'].append(sub_form(request.POST))

    # update some fields on forms to render them on the template
    for f in context['forms']:
        f.model_name = f.Meta.model._meta.model_name
        f.sub_forms = {x.Meta.model._meta.verbose_name: x for x in f.__class__.__subclasses__()}
        f.sub_options = f.sub_forms.keys()    # this is for rendering selector on the form for the follow-up forms

    page = loader.get_template(template)
    response = HttpResponse(page.render(context, request))
    return response
```

**forms.py**

```
class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Place
        fields = ('name', 'address',)

class RestaurantForm(PlaceForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Restaurant
        fields = ('cuisine', 'website',)

class SportFieldForm(PlaceForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.SportField
        fields = ('sport',)
```

**templates/inheritance.html**

```
<body>
  {% for form in forms %}
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% if form.sub_options %}
      <select class="change-place" name="{{ form.model_name }}_sub_selected">
          {% for option in form.sub_options %}
          <option value="{{ option }}" {% if option == form.sub_selected %}selected{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
      {% endif %}
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
```

What I didn't make here is saving the form to the database. But it should be rather trivial using the similar snippet:

```
for f in context['forms']:
    if f.is_valid():
        f.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of way you can handle multiple froms in django. The easiest way to use i[nlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory).

in your **froms.py**:

```
forms .models import your model
    
class ParentFrom(froms.From):
          # add fields from your parent model 
        
Restaurant = inlineformset_factory(your parent model name,Your Child model name,fields=('cuisine',# add fields from your child model),extra=1,can_delete=False,)

SportField = inlineformset_factory(your parent model name,Your Child model name,fields=('sport',# add fields from your child model),extra=1,can_delete=False,)
```

in your **views.py**

```
if ParentFrom.is_valid():
            ParentFrom = ParentFrom.save(commit=False)
            Restaurant = Restaurant(request.POST, request.FILES,) #if you want to add images or files then use request.FILES.
            SportField =  SportField(request.POST)

            if   Restaurant.is_valid() and SportField.is_valid():
                ParentFrom.save()
                Restaurant.save()
                SportField.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(#your redirect url)
```

**#html**

```
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
       
        {% csrf_token %}
        #{{ Restaurant.errors}} #if you want to show error
        {{ Restaurant}}
        {{ SportField}}
        {{form}}
</form>
```

you can use simple JavaScript in your html for hide and show your any froms fields

Comment: do you save three objects? Why?

Comment: form object is parent and  others two  are child. You can add multiple child forms as your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Add a PlaceType table, and a FK, e.g. type_of_place, to the Place table:

```
    class PlaceType(Model):
        types = models.CharField(max_length=40) # sportsfield, restaurants, bodega, etc. 
    
    class Place(Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        type_of_place = models.ForeignKey('PlaceType', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Restaurant(Place):
        cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        website = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

This allows you to create a new Place as either SportsField, restaurant or some other type which you can easily add in the future.

When a new place is created, you'll use the standard CreateView and Model Form. Then, you can display a second form which also uses a standard CreateView that is based on the *type_of_place* value. These forms can be on the same page (and with javascript on the browser side, you'll hide the second form until the first one is saved) or on separate pages--which may be more practical if you intend to have lots of extra columns. The two key points are as follows:

1. type_of_place determines which form, view, and model to use. For
   example, if user chooses a "Sports Field" for type_of_place, then
   you know to route the user off to the SportsField model form;
2. CreateViews are designed for creating just one object/model. When
   used as intended, they are simple and easy to maintain.

Comment: not sure to undestand. If I use a `CreateView` based on the model `Place` then a `Place` will be saved after the first form.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra yes, a place will be saved with an (optional) type_of_place.

Comment: but I don't want to save a `Place`. I want to save the proper object, e.g. `Restaurant`

Comment: @RuggeroTurra, if you have a object that switches from one model to another, as the end-user supplies information in a form, you'll want to handle what happens when they only supply only some of the information (e.g 'name' and 'address' but nothing else).  Just to be clear: you're saving `Place` for incomplete places, and saving e.g. `Restaurant` once the user has selected `type_of_place` and any other required fields on that model object.

Comment: ok, by they way you just described what I want... not sure how to implement. For example, how to write the second CreateView? How to redirect from the first to the second?